# Invoke 2 REST services on Playframework to compose a response

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I am having a problem with Webservice invoking on Playframework. I have an example where I invoke one service and use it as the response to my route

```
def test = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val baseUrl = "serviceURL"

    WS.url(baseUrl).get().map { response =>
      val result = response.json.asOpt[List[Person]]

      Ok(views.html.test(result.get))
    }
}
```

This works fine, but now I want to invoke 2 Webservices, but I can't do that to compose a response because the `WS.url().get()` calls return a `Future` and I don't know how to extract the `Option` from inside of it. So  the question is:

How do I get the `Option` from inside the `Future`?

I tried doing this:

```
def test = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val baseUrl = "serviceURL"

    val wsResult = WS.url(baseUrl).get().map { response =>
      val result = response.json.asOpt[List[Person]]
    }

    Ok(views.html.test(wsResult.get))
}
```

But as I said `wsResult` has an instance of `Future` and not `Option`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the second webservice inside the map block of first webservice and change map to flatMap in first service call.

```
val wsResult = WS.url(baseUrl).get().flatMap { response =>
      val result = response.json.asOpt[List[Person]]
     secondwebserice.map{ res=>

    Ok(views.html.test(result.get))
 }
}
```

Since your question, I guess, the two web services are independent, so you can also use for comprehension as

```
val wsResult1 = WS.url(baseUrl).get().map { response =>
      val result = response.json.asOpt[List[Person]]
    }
val wsResult2 = WS.url(baseUrl2).get().map { response =>
      val result = response.json.asOpt[List[Person]]
    }

val result = for {
r1<-wsResult1 
r2<-wsResult2 
}yield(r1.get++r2.get)

result .map {res=>  Ok(views.html.test(res)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PlayFramework yet except for Play-Json, and wouldn't have answered if you'd gotten a better-informed answer sooner.  But I think you want to return

```
wsResult.flatMap { Ok(views.html.test(_)) }
```

This constructs a new future wrapped around the results in wsResult.